# How to print SVG file with .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, svg, printing

I understand this is probably a dumb question to ask but i am stuck.

I have one **SVG** file. The file contains one design which i would like to **plot using Graphtec FC8600** plotter.

I have plotter installed on my windows machine.

I am designing one windows form application which will plot the selected SVG file using graphtec plotter.

My initial understanding says, i can do plotting similar to printing. When i try to plot the SVG file using printDocument, the plotter receives the command but plots the SVG unrendered content, not the actual image.

I think i am missing something important here. I have already gone through available resources on google and SO.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `WebBrowser` control to print your svg file.

You can use `Navigate` method to navigate to the file path and then using [`Print`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print(v=vs.110).aspx) method, you can send the file to default printer. If you need to choose the printer, you can use [`ShowPrintDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0xbfs8f9(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

**Example**

```
private void PrintFile(string fileName)
{
    using (var wb = new WebBrowser())
    {
        wb.Navigate(fileName);
        while (wb.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        wb.Print();
    }
}
```

**MSDN Example**

- [How to: Print with a WebBrowser Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You are welcome. I had no problem when printing an svg file this way. Let me know if you have any question about the answer :)